# Stripe Cashier form is not submitted

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with stripe cashier; i get

> This customer has no attached payment source

I don't know why, hope someone could help me... many thanks in advance.

I tried to look a lot of tutorials but i can't get any good results.

Maybe it's a problem with the token ? i tried to enter the credit card test :

4242 4242 4242 4242

I would like to use it as a subscription.

Here my view

```
<div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

               <form action="{{route('checkout')}}" method="post" id="payment-form">
                   {{csrf_field()}}
                   <div class="form-row">
                       <label for="card-element">
                           Credit or debit card
                       </label>
                       <div id="card-element">
                           <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                       </div>

                       <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                       <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                   </div>

                   <button>Submit Payment</button>
               </form>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>

<script>

    // Create a Stripe client
    var stripe = Stripe('.....');

    // Create an instance of Elements
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            lineHeight: '18px',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element
    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
    card.mount('#card-element');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
    });

    // Handle form submission
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the user if there was an error
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here my checkout controller :

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Stripe::setApiKey('.....');

            $user = User::find(1);
            $user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($request->stripeToken);

            return 'Subscription successful, you get the course!';
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is most likely caused either by incorrect Stripe plan configuration or by an invalid token being passed to Stripe when you're trying to subscribe the user to the plan. 

The first step in debugging this is to log in to your Stripe control panel and confirm that you have a plan called `monthly` and that it's correctly configured. 

After confirming you have the plan configured correctly via Stripe, you need to confirm `checkout` is receiving the stripeToken: do this by adding `dd($request->stripeToken)` to your controller (before the `try/catch` block) and check it is not empty.